# SystemStackError while installing ruby-2.2.2 on Mac OS 10.10.3 using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am getting the follow error while installing ruby 2.2.2 on Mac using rvm

```
installing bundle gems:       /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                              minitest-5.4.3.gem
                              power_assert-0.2.2.gem
                              test-unit-3.0.8.gem
./tool/rbinstall.rb:728:in `block in <main>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

It seems some gem is blowing up the stack. I don't know what gem is and why its doing so.

Here is the full log:

```
+__rvm_make:0> make install
config.status: creating x86_64-darwin14-fake.rb
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib  -install_name /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/libruby.2.2.0.dylib -current_version 2.2.0 -compatibility_version 2.2.0  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -framework CoreFoundation  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -framework CoreFoundation
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
generating makefile exts.mk
Failed to configure -test-/win32/console. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/dln. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/dln/empty. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure -test-/win32/fd_setsize. It will not be installed.
configuring socket
Failed to configure win32. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure win32ole. It will not be installed.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default bigdecimal libraries
installing default date_core libraries
installing digest libraries
installing default digest libraries
installing default sha2 libraries
installing default fiddle libraries
installing default console libraries
installing default libraries
installing default nkf libraries
installing default openssl libraries
installing default pathname libraries
installing default psych libraries
installing default pty libraries
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
installing default ripper libraries
checking ../.././parse.y and ../.././ext/ripper/eventids2.c
linking shared-object socket.bundle
installing default socket libraries
installing default syslog libraries
installing tcltklib libraries
installing default tcltklib libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: `ruby' is up to date.
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- --disable-gems -r./x86_64-darwin14-fake ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc"
installing binary commands:   /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
installing base libraries:    /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib
installing arch files:        /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
installing pkgconfig data:    /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/pkgconfig
installing command scripts:   /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
installing library scripts:   /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0
installing common headers:    /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0
installing manpages:          /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/share/man/man1
installing extension objects: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
installing extension objects: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
installing extension objects: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
installing extension headers: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14
installing extension scripts: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0
installing extension scripts: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
installing extension scripts: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
installing extension headers: /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby
installing default gems:      /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                              bigdecimal 1.2.6
                              io-console 0.4.3
                              json 1.8.1
                              psych 2.0.8
                              rake 10.4.2
                              rdoc 4.2.0
installing bundle gems:       /Users/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                              minitest-5.4.3.gem
                              power_assert-0.2.2.gem
                              test-unit-3.0.8.gem
./tool/rbinstall.rb:728:in `block in <main>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

Any help on how do debug this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.2
```

It worked to me.